# Alguém que conhece o framework Ulkit

Tags: css

Estou começando a aprender o framework Css Ulkit, estou tentando fazer um menu responsivo que se adapte ao celular. Quando está em uma resolução de celular, não faz nada como nos exemplos que no site Ulkit faz, se alguém que entenda desse framework puder me ajudar.

Abaixo o codigo:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/uikit.min.js" />
    <script src="uikit.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <nav class="uk-navbar">
            <ul class="uk-navbar-nav uk-hidden-small">
                <li class="uk-active"><a href="" class="uk-navbar-nav-subtitle">Active<div>Subtitle</div></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="uk-navbar-nav-subtitle">Item<div>Subtitle</div></a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#offcanvas-1" class="uk-navbar-toggle uk-visible-small" data-uk-offcanvas=""></a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Era para aparecer um menu lateral -->
    <div id="offcanvas-1" class="uk-offcanvas">
        <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">
            <div class="uk-panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consetetur</a> sadipscing elitr.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elizer tente usar a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

E teste o site em um emulador como este:
http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Caso redimensione o próprio navegador não esqueça de atualizar a página para garantir.

Comment: Não deu certo Ricardo, enfim fiquei curioso para que serve esta meta tag?

Comment: Essa meta tag manipula onde e com quais proporções seu website aparece. Essa meta tag tem uma série de valores de content que você pode manipular afim de personalizar o visual do site. Ela deve ser usada em conjunto com as _medias queries_. Esse link explica sua utilização em detalhes: http://tableless.com.br/manipulando-metatag-viewport/